# Extracting conditional rows from a list of dataframes in a loop

Tags: r, function, dataframe, lapply, mapply

In my `split(w7, w7$study.name)[48]` call below there are 4 rows for which variable `control == FALSE`.

But I'm wondering why `ctlistG(split(w7, w7$study.name)[48])` returns only one of such rows?

***ps.** I suspect, instead of `lapply()` I should have used `mapply()` in `ctlistG()`.*

**Reproducible R code:**

```
ctlist <- function(List, cont=FALSE, pos=1, outcom=1){

 if(!inherits(List, "list")) List <- list(List)  
  
h <- setNames(lapply(List, function(i) i[i$control==cont & i$post == pos & i$outcome == outcom, , drop = FALSE]), names(List)) 

Filter(NROW, h) }

#====================

ctlistG <- function(m){
  
  input <- setNames(lapply(m, function(i) rev(expand.grid(outcom = seq_len(max(i$outcome, na.rm = TRUE)), pos = seq_len(max(i$post, na.rm = TRUE))))), names(m))
  
  lapply(input, function(i) ctlist(m, cont = FALSE, pos = i$pos, outcom = i$outcom))   }

#==================== EXAMPLE OF USE:
w7 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/w7.csv')

ctlistG(split(w7, w7$study.name)[48])  # I expect 4 rows not 1 below!

#$VanBe_Jng_KenA
#$VanBe_Jng_KenA$VanBe_Jng_KenA
#        study.name YofPub group.name  n  d
#406 VanBe_Jng_KenA   2012         NA 34 NA
```

Comment: If you call `w7 %>% filter(study.name == 'VanBe_Jng_KenA', !control)` you get your four rows. Then you further filter on `post` and `outcom`. I would suggest looking here first. And then I would suggest you explain what you are actually trying to do, because it is not very clear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need 4 rows, based on the function, we may need `Map` instead of `lapply`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(input, function(inp) 
      do.call(rbind, Map(function(p, o)
   do.call(rbind, lapply(m, function(m1)
    m1[m1$control == FALSE & m1$post == p & m1$outcome ==o, , drop = FALSE])),
      inp$pos, inp$outcom))))
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- split(w7, w7$study.name)
m <- lst1[48]
```

Comment: @rnorouzian in that case, you need to remove the `lapply(m, ` because it is no longer a list

Comment: Arun, can you please add that to your answer?  Note that 'input' also will be a data.frame.

Comment: @rnorouzian `lapply` is used only when 'm' is a `list` of datasets.  If it is a single one.  either you wrap it in a `list and use the same command i..e. `lapply(list(m), function(m1),...` or `use m directly i.e. `m[m$control == FALSE & ....`

Comment: @rnorouzian I was just driving.  That question seems to be answered

Comment: @rnorouzian I think the solution in that post is the same as I mentioned here i.e. wrapping `list`

Comment: @rnorouzian either way you need a condition to check.  if the `m` is not a list and data.frame, then do i..e `if(!is.list(m) && is.data.frame(m)) m <- list(m)` and use the same code

Comment: @rnorouzian yes, otherwise, you can have to make lots of changes

Comment: @rnorouzian I get the output as `list()` for both